# Xam.Plugin.Media in xamarin.android get destination folder beforehand

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In a Xamarin.Android project I'm using Xam.Plugin.Media for taking pictures
I want to know beforehand in which folder the pictures will be stored
There is any way to know that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By following the source code [Xam.Plugin.Media](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/src/Media.Plugin.Android/MediaPickerActivity.cs)

`TakePhotoAsync`-->`CreateMediaIntent`-->`MediaPickerActivity.GetOutputMediaFile`

You can find the default directory :

`var directory = saveToAlbum ? Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(mediaType) : context.GetExternalFilesDir(mediaType);`

So the plugin just provide tow kinds of path to store, one is `GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory` the other is `GetExternalFilesDir`. As default, the `saveToAlbum` is false, it will store in the **data/media/Android/data/your.package.name/files/**.  If the `saveToAlbum` is true the photo will be stored in **DCIM** folder.

Test the following code in Andorid 6.0:

```
takePhoto = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.takephoto);
takePhoto.Click += async (sender, args) =>
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
         return;
    }
    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
         Directory = "Sample",
         Name = "test.jpg"
     });
     if (file == null)
            return; 
};
```

You can find the test.jpg is stored here:

[image]

> I want to know beforehand in which folder the pictures will be stored

The plugin does not provide the interface that can get the `var directory`. So you can not get the path by coding in advance.